# No new row with Datagrid Editing after updating ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have been having an issue with a `DataGrid` not making a new empty row after a new record has been entered.

It seems to only occur after updating the `ObversableCollection<T>`.

I use this to bind to the collection:

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
    DataContext = this; 
    InitializeComponent();       

    CollectionLists.CalculationTableSourceCollection(CalculationTblSourceObserv, @"section", @"sectionAll");
    CalculationTableGrid.ItemsSource = CalculationTblSourceObserv;
    }
public ObservableCollection<CalculationListTbl> CalculationTblSourceObserv { get; set; } 
 = new ObservableCollection<CalculationListTbl>();
}
```

This is my code for updating my `ObversableCollection<T>`:

```
class CollectionLists
{
public static void CalculationTableSourceCollection(ObservableCollection<CalculationListTbl> observable,
  string section, string sectionAll)
    {
            using (DatabaseDataContext dataContext = new DatabaseDataContext(MainWindow.InstanceConnectionString))
        {
            observable.Clear();
            var source = DatabaseQueries.CalculationTableSourceAll(sectionAll, dataContext);
            if (source == null) return;
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                observable.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CalculationTableGrid" Grid.Column="2" 
       AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
       Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="12" AlternationCount="2" 
       CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" 
       CanUserDeleteRows="True" GridLinesVisibility="None" 
       CellEditEnding="CalculationTableGrid_OnCellEditEnding" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="項目" 
           Binding="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=ListItems, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

And I use this method to update the `dataGrid`:

```
private void CalculationTableGrid_OnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
     ShiftTypeData.UserInputData.AddNewDataShiftInputRecords(e, MainUserId, EmployeesNameNumberPairsAll, CalculationTblListObserv, DateFilter);
     CollectionLists.CalculationTableSourceCollection(CalculationTblSourceObserv, @"section", @"sectionAll");               
}
```

So everything works fine, the `DataGrid' is updated, the database is correctly updated and the`ObversableCollection`is updated. However the`DataGrid` should be added a new row after the new record is inserted, but this is what it does.

This is what it does,

[image]

However, commenting out this line `CollectionLists.CalculationTableSourceCollection(CalculationTblSourceObserv, @"section", @"sectionAll");` in the `CalculationTableGrid_OnCellEditEnding` event allows it to correctly behave and an empty row is added after the new record is made, see below:

[image]

What is going on here, I can't get this to work correctly, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The issue is that the CellEditEnding event will be raised when the new item is added and then you immediately clear it in your CalculationTableSourceCollection method...why are you even calling the CalculationTableSourceCollection method in the CellEditEnding event handler?

Comment: @mm8, to update the collection. I thought you were supposed to update every time you change something?

Comment: @mm8, ahhh, I see what I did wrong. You are absolutely correct!!!

Comment: Does that mean that your issue has been solved? Should I post my comment as an answer?

Comment: @mm8, Yes you solved my issue. Also could you add a small explaination on what happens with a  `ObservableCollection<T>` when `INotifyPropertyChanged` is invoked, as it seems that my method `CalculationTableSourceCollection` is unnecessary for both adding and deleted items from the collection, as when when `INotifyPropertyChanged` is invoked it changes to the collection for you. (That is if my understanding is correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `CellEditEnding` event will be raised when the new item is added and then you immediately clear your `CalculationTableSourceCollection` in your `CalculationTableSourceCollection` method.

You don't have to call the `CalculationTableSourceCollection` method in the `CellEditEnding` event handler at all.

Any item that you add or remove to an `ObservableCollection<T>` will automatically show up in the `DataGrid`. This is what makes an `ObservableCollection<T>` different from a `List<T>`. The latter doesn't implement the [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

Comment: Why doesn't a `DataGrid` update when changing content of an `ObservableCollection<T>`? I have a `ComboBox` where I change Staff members, which means I have to re-populate the `ObservableCollection<T>` with a link query, however the `DataGrid` data does not update. Do I need to update the `DataGrid.ItemSoruce` again? See the first set of code in my question as to how I am binding to the `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: Done, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135024/change-out-observablecollection-upon-combobox-change

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are updating property `CalculationTblSourceObserv` but you have bounded the property `ListItems` in the xaml. so either bind `CalculationTblSourceObserv` in xaml or you can do following.

In your question I can't see which part of code does the property 'ListItems' is present, which is the property binded to the datagrid. Hopefully this is in a view model.

So either your property 'ListItems' is not getting updated or if it is getting updated then your xaml is not notified about that change. Your view model code should notify the xaml that a property has been updated. This is done via Raising a property changed event which can be done like this:

```
public string ListItems
{
    get { return listItems; }
    set
    {
         listItems= value;
         // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
         OnPropertyChanged("ListItems");
     }
}

  // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
  protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
  }
```

Further refer to link: [How to: Implement Property Change Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `listItems` is a column in the SQL server tabel in the `LINQ to SQL`.

Comment: @KyloRen So are you inserting those records into the observable collection ? If yes then specify that observable collection name in xaml as suggested in the answer.

Comment: So how do I update the database using the observable collection?

Comment: @KyloRen What part of the code are you updating the database now ? Moreover that is a separate question. So if your original question is answered then we are good I guess.

Comment: Using LINQ to SQL, so `ListItems` is a property of that auto generated class. Anyway, I found the issue with @mm8 help. But I always up vote those who helped me out as the link was helpful.