# Change out ObservableCollection upon ComboBox change

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

This is not so much a question that I am stuck on, but a question as to if there is a better way. It works as it stands, but I want to get a better understand if I could.

**Why do I always have to update the `DataGrid.ItemSource` when I am using an `ObservableCollection<T>` for binding?**

I am binding the `ObservableCollection<T>` to the `DataGrid` using the below code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
         DataContext = this; 
         InitializeComponent();

         CalcObservable = 
             DatabaseQueries.ShiftInputSourceObserv(SelectedEmployee.Key, DateFilter);

         MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = CalcObservable;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CalcTable> CalcObservable { get; set; } 
          = new ObservableCollection<CalcTable>();
}
```

And this is the function that gets the data from the DataBase,

```
internal class DatabaseQueries
{
    public static ObservableCollection<CalcTable> ShiftInputSourceObserv(int staffNo, DateTime date)
    {
        using (DatabaseDataContext dataContext = new DatabaseDataContext(MainWindow.InstanceConnectionString))
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<CalcTable>
                    (dataContext.CalcTables.Where(
                         p => p.Staff_No == staffNo && 
                         p.Year_No == date.Year && 
                         p.Month_No == date.Month)
                         .OrderBy(p => p.Column_Index)); 
        }
    }
}
```

I then use a `ComboBox` change event to update the `ObservableCollection<T>`. `SelectedEmployee.Key` is bound to the `ComboBox` and changes the selected employee upon selection:

```
 private void NumbersComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 { 
      CalcObservable = 
         DatabaseQueries.ShiftInputSourceObserv(SelectedEmployee.Key, DateFilter);

      MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = CalcObservable;
 }
```

I was under the impression that changing the `ObservableCollection<T>` would update **WITHOUT** having to use the  `MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = CalcObservable;` line again?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Isn't it a new instance?

Comment: Instead of assigning to `CalcObservable` in `NumbersComboBox_SelectionChanged`, try clearing the existing collection and adding the items from the return value of `DatabaseQueries.ShiftInputSourceObserv` to the existing collection (i.e, `CalcObservable `)

Comment: `ObservableCollection ` will notify the UI when you add/remove items. But what you are doing is creating a new instance

Comment: @Pikoh, That is what I suspected. So I need to clear the collection and add data that way then?

Comment: Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `CalcObservable` and bind it from DataContext instead of assigning it in constructor

Comment: Yes,as @YacoubMassad suggest

Comment: @grek40, could you expand on that, I am not sure I know how to do that?

Comment: @YacoubMassad, I am guessing adding the data via a loop then?

Comment: Yes. Clear the data first, and then add the new items to the collection.

Answer (score 3):

> I am binding the `ObservableCollection<T>` to the `DataGrid` using the below code ...

No, you don't bind it. You set the `ItemsSource` property to the value of your `CalcObservable` property.

You are then setting the `CalcObservable` property to a *new* `ObservableCollection<T>` in your `NumbersComboBox_SelectionChanged` event handler. This won't somehow automatically update the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid`.

If you actually do *bind* to the `CalcObservable` property you could refresh the `DataGrid` provided that your class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and you raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `CalcObservable` property:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();

        CalcObservable = DatabaseQueries.ShiftInputSourceObserv(SelectedEmployee.Key, DateFilter);
        MyDataGrid.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding(nameof(CalcObservable)) { Source = this });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<CalcTable> _calcObservable = new ObservableCollection<CalcTable>();
    public ObservableCollection<CalcTable> CalcObservable
    {
        get { return _calcObservable; }
        set { _calcObservable = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CalcObservable)); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

The other option is to clear the existing instance of the `ObservableCollection<T>` and add new items to it instead of creating a new Collection each time you want to update the DataGrid.

Comment: Give me a bit, I have been trying to implement this. I gotta be honest, it goes over my head a little bit. The way you set the binding on the datagrid.

Comment: Is how you define a binding *programmatically*. You might as well set up the binding in your XAML markup: <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CalcObservable}" ... />. But then you should *not* set the ItemsSource property programmatically because then you clear the binding that you have defined in your XAML markup.

Comment: I have solved the issue with the comments, but your answer is very intriguing. As you know you can only use one `OnPropertyChanged` method, and the method you show does not allow my other `OnPropertyChanged` properties to work. Why did you set the `ObservableCollection<CalcTable>` that way? Is that not the old way to do this, as an ObservableCollection<T>` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` automatically? I have upvoted for the help you showed, but I want to understand this answer more.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean? The point is that you should *bind* the ItemsSource property to the CalcObservable source property. Whether you set up the binding in the XAML markup or in the C# code doesn't matter. And the implementation of the OnPropertyChanged method has nothing to do with this really. Is simply raised the PropertyChanged event as usual.