# WPF Datgrid not updating

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, observablecollection

I am having problems with my WPF Datagrid updating in the UI.
I am trying to use MVVM.
I am using an observable collection:

```
 public ObservableCollection<OCInspections> MyInspectionList
        {
            get { return _MyInspectionList; }
            set { _MyInspectionList = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyInspectionList"); }
        }
```

Which is attached to an IcollectionView:

```
MyInspectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyInspectionList);
```

with property...

```
public ICollectionView MyInspectionView 
        {
            get { return _MyInspectionView; }
            set { _MyInspectionView = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyInspectionView"); }
        }
```

which is attached to a datagrid items source:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="InspectionGrid" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" SelectionUnit="FullRow" ItemsSource="{Binding MyInspectionView, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" SelectedValue="{Binding  Path=MySelectedInspection,Mode=TwoWay}"   >
```

When I filter the grid, the UI updates:

```
public string ToggleText
        {
            get {
                return _ToggleText ?? (_ToggleText = "Open Orders"); }
            set {
                _ToggleText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ToggleText");
                FilterMe();        
            }
        }

    private void FilterMe()
            {
                MyInspectionView.Filter = O =>
               {
                   OCInspections P = O as OCInspections;
                   if (ToggleState == true)
                   {
                       return P.CompleteDate == null;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       return P.CompleteDate != null;
                   }                 
               };    
            }
```

However, there are two oddities, which may be related:

1. If I try to Sort the grid the UI doesn't update.

   private void Click_DefaultSort()
               {
                   MyInspectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("StopReasonID", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                   MyInspectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("StartedDate", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                   MyInspectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ReceiptDate", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

   ```
               }
   ```
2. If a user enters data in the new row and I add it to the observable collection, it will add and show in the UI, but it will not automatically add the next new blank row.  However, if I click on another row or press enter it will add the new blank row:

   - before clicking add row button
     [image]

after clicking the add button
[image]

after clicking any existing row or pressing enter:
[image]

I think these two items may be related which is why I'm including them in the same question.
this is the closest thing I found for the second problem as an example:
[No new row with Datagrid Editing after updating ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115099/no-new-row-with-datagrid-editing-after-updating-observablecollection)

EDIT: another observation is that the binding is throwing these warnings, but I have been unsuccessful at resolving:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=5405340) for Binding (hash=39717249)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'MyInspectionView'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=5405340): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.ItemsSource (hash=42463340)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=5405340): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=5405340): Found data context element: DataGrid (hash=42463340) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=5405340): Activate with root item MainWindowViewModel (hash=63685038)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=5405340):   At level 0 - for MainWindowViewModel.MyInspectionView found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(MyInspectionView)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=5405340): Replace item at level 0 with MainWindowViewModel (hash=63685038), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(MyInspectionView)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=5405340): GetValue at level 0 from MainWindowViewModel (hash=63685038) using RuntimePropertyInfo(MyInspectionView): ListCollectionView (hash=48179284)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=5405340): TransferValue - got raw value ListCollectionView (hash=48179284)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 84 : BindingExpression (hash=5405340): TransferValue - implicit converter produced ListCollectionView (hash=48179284)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=5405340): TransferValue - using final value ListCollectionView (hash=48179284)
```

Comment: "the binding is throwing these warnings" - they are not warnings, just tracing info. "Created BindingExpression (hash=5405340) for Binding" suggests that Binding was successful

Comment: You need to .Refresh() your collectionview for filters to change anything in the view.

Comment: I have tried:  MyInspectionView.SortDescriptions.Clear(); at the begining, MyInspectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyInspectionList), and MyInspectionView.Refresh(),  No luck.  I note that when I visually inspect in debug MyInspectionView, it is sorted.  The system is calling the onpropertychanged and get for the Myinspectionview property.  Still not updating.  Something in xaml?  But I have mode=two way???